# my code is not working how i expected it to

Tags: shell

I tried to run an echo command after a java application and it doesn't work

```
#!/bin/bash
functest(){
echo "starting"
java -jar /home/Alex/Desktop/server/server.jar
}

cd server
echo test
functest
echo test2
```

Comment: You aren't running the Java code in the background, so `functest` doesn't return until the program exits. The `echo test2` simply isn't being reached.

Comment: what do you mean by "You aren't running the Java code in the background."